# Executing a Function at a Specific time

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a timer running in my app which I want to stop and start according to local time.
So I need something like this:

```
if ( time = 08:00) {StartTimer();}
If ( time = 18:00) {StopTimer();} //This can be done from the timer event itself
```

Is there a way to do this **without** using another timer?
I can stop the timer from within the timer event itself, but how will i start it again?

Comment: afaik you need the second timer.. but where is the problem with it?

Comment: Is the only reason you don't want to use a timer because you can't start it again? You can just use a second timer to start the first one at a set time.

Comment: I already have 2 timers, and am afraid that adding another one will impact performance

Comment: Judging from the comments and answers it seems like i'll always need at least one timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the timer's interval to 14 hours instead of stopping it or keep it running with short interval and checking additional condition (the time of the day) internally.

Comment: Who said that? You? Isn't that against your question?

Comment: Sorry I have 1 timer that ticks every x seconds, i need to stop THAT timer at 18:00 and start it again at 08:00

Comment: Yes, but you can set the interval after 18:00 to 14 hours, and then change it back to the original value in next iteration. (I would prefer checking the time anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

1) Create a console app that does what you're looking for.

2) Use the Windows "Scheduled Tasks" functionality to have that console app executed at the time you need it to run

or

You can also look at this example:-

```
   using System;
   using System.Threading;

    public class TimerExample {

// The method that is executed when the timer expires. Displays
// a message to the console.
private static void TimerHandler(object state) {

    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}",
        DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff"), state);
}

public static void Main() {

    // Create a new TimerCallback delegate instance that 
    // references the static TimerHandler method. TimerHandler 
    // will be called when the timer expires.
    TimerCallback handler = new TimerCallback(TimerHandler);

    // Create the state object that is passed to the TimerHandler
    // method when it is triggered. In this case a message to display.
    string state = "Timer expired.";

    Console.WriteLine("{0} : Creating Timer.",
        DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff"));

    // Create a Timer that fires first after 2 seconds and then every
    // second.
    using (Timer timer = new Timer(handler, state, 2000, 1000)) {

        int period;

        // Read the new timer interval from the console until the
        // user enters 0 (zero). Invalid values use a default value
        // of 0, which will stop the example.
        do {

            try {
                period = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            } catch {
                period = 0;
            }

            // Change the timer to fire using the new interval starting
            // immediately.
            if (period > 0) timer.Change(0, period);

        } while (period > 0);
    }

    // Wait to continue.
    Console.WriteLine("Main method complete. Press Enter.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a thread that ticks every second.

There you can check if you want to start or stop your timer.

Read the folowing: [Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

In your thread add something like:

```
if (CurrentTime == "08:00")
   StartTimer();
else if  if (CurrentTime == "18:00")
   StopTimer();
Thread.Sleep(1000); // Makes the Thread Sleep 1 Second
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however adding a thread to my app is outside the scope of the application itself

Comment: @Josefvz You could use invokes and delegates to communicate with your application. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since you need at least one timer running always (to detect when it's 8 in the morning) then you could simply have just a single timer that runs all day.

Whenever the timer ticks, check the time. If it isn't between 0800 and 1800 just return without doing anything and wait for the next tick.

You could try increasing the timer interval to a value that gets you to e.g. 17:55 and then decrease it again, but there will not be any measurable performance difference so IMHO this is work for no benefit.